# Перестает работать функция onсlick в innerHTML, если в html скрипту добавить type='module'

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется html документ, фрагмент из него:

```
<body class="body">
  <button class="hello">hello</button>  
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

и к нему index.js скрипт:

```
const body = document.querySelector('.body')
const helloButton = document.querySelector('.hello')

helloButton.addEventListener('click', (e)=> hello(100500))
const x = 5;

function hello(number) {
  console.log('button',number)
}

for(let i=0;i<x;i++) {
  const button = `<button onclick='hello(${i})'}>${i}</button>`
  body.innerHTML += button;
}
```

Вопрос 1: в таком виде на страницу в цикле добавляется 5 кнопок, по нажатию на каждую срабатывает функция hello, в консоль выводится номер кнопки.
Все ломается если при подключении скрипта в html, указать что это модуль, не могу понять почему:

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

Кнопки добавляются на страницу, но при нажатии получаю ошибки:

```
index.html:52 Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:52:9)
```

Вопрос 2: при наличии этого цикла с кнопками, нажатие на кнопку, которая уже есть в html, которой добавлен eventListener через js

```
<button class="hello">hello</button>

helloButton.addEventListener('click', (e)=> hello(100500))
```

Нажатие на кнопку ничего не дает, eventListener не отрабатывает, не важно стоит ли type='module' или нет. Если цикл убрать, кнопка работает в обоих вариантах.
Прошу объясните, гуглеж и stackOverflow на конкретно этот случай ответа не нашел, даже на английском.

Comment: в случае с модулем, вам надо экспортировать функцию hello `export function hello`. Подробнее [про type=module](https://learn.javascript.ru/modules-intro). По поводу цикла и не рабочего клика - вы перезаписываете элементы(старый удаляется, новый создается). Когда элемент удаляется, с ним удаляются и все его события.

Comment: 1) Eсли я буду создавать в цикле кнопки через document.createElement('button') и потом добавлять им eventListener, все будет работать. Экспортировать функцию мне никуда не надо, в данном случае это огрызок для примера, в моем проекте модулей несколько, из них экспортируются функции в index.js. Проблема почему то возникает именно при создании кнопок через innerHTML. 2) По поводу перезаписи кнопки - она не перезаписывается, она не участвует в цикле, это отдельный элемент.

Comment: @AlexNoob по поводу модуля не знаю, но касательно перезаписи SwaD прав, попробуй через insertAdjacentHTML вставить кнопки и увидеш разницу.

Comment: @Armen Если уж манипулировать DOM, то лучш document.createElement. Это сразу и Node создает и все события с атрибутами можно задать и передавать куда угодно и как угодно. А так, сначала добавь, потом отбери, потом обработай.... Ну это мое мнение.

Comment: @SwaD ну да, полностю сагласен, только не понял как это противаречит с вставкой через insertAdjacentHTML? надо же этот созданный элемент добавить в дерево как то.

Comment: @Armen Как по мне, когда "кнопки" создаются текстом, то собственно все равно, как их в DOM добавлять :)

Comment: @SwaD только дашло) метод то страку принимает)) надо insertAdjacentElement ну или тому подобное)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модули - это "независимые" компоненты. Все объявленные переменные и функции доступны только внутри модуля. Для обмена переменными и функциями используются ключевые слова export/import.

Рассмотрим ваш пример с модулем и кнопкой.

Кнопка у вас создается так:

```
`<button onclick='hello(${i})'}>${i}</button>`
```

Где на событие клика должна присутствовать функция hello в текущем локальном или глобальном окружении, однако функция объявлена в модуле и не доступна из текущего окружения кнопки.

Я вижу 2 рещения:

1. Создавать кнопку с помощью document.createElement и вешать ей событие клика через  addEventListener в том же модуле
2. После объявления функции hello выполнить `window.hello = hello;`. Это положит функцию hello в глобальное пространство браузера (не рекомендую)

---

Вот ваш HTML контейнер

```
<body class="body">
  <button class="hello">hello</button>  
</body>
```

Вы создали собыие клика:

```
const helloButton = document.querySelector('.hello')
helloButton.addEventListener('click', (e)=> hello(100500))
```

Далее вы в цикле каждую итерацию удаляете все из контейнера и заново добавляете.

Вот этот код

```
for(let i=0;i<x;i++) {
  const button = `<button onclick='hello(${i})'}>${i}</button>`
  body.innerHTML += button;
}
```

, если разложить его на более мелкие части выглядит так:

```
for(let i=0;i<x;i++) {
  // Создали строку
  const button = `<button onclick='hello(${i})'}>${i}</button>`;
  // Получили содержимое контейнера в виде строки
  const prevHTML = body.innerHTML;
  // Говорим, добавь строку, но преобразуй ее в HTML элементы
  body.innerHTML = prevHTML + button;
}
```

т.е. каждая итерация улаляет все содержимое и устанавливает заново НОВОЕ.
Все события, которые были у удаляемых элементов удаляются.

Comment: спасибо! про модули кажется понял

Comment: Про историю с затиранием кнопок так и не могу понять. Ведь я использую оператор +=,я не обнуляю контейнер в начале каждого цикла, а плюсую к нему, условно говоря у меня на 1 итерации есть кнопка helloButton, которая уже есть в верстке, к ней добавляется кнопка button0, на 2 итерации есть уже 2 кнопки, к ним добавляется button1 и т.д.

Comment: нашел в документации про innerHTML, действительно все содержимое удаляется, вопрос закрыт

Comment: @AlexNoob += это просто краткая запись -> возьми что есть, добавь новое и сохрани